# C++ Creating a 10x10 grid with a random character in each spot?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and taking a beginner course for it this summer. Our first project needs to output a 10x10 grid. The spots are labeled 0-99. Each spot also has a random character. It can be either a upper or lower case letter from the ASCII list. Example output: (assume this is 10x10 not 3x3)

```
99.f  98.c  97.Q
96.D  95.Y  94.b
93.x  92.H  91.o
```

Im stuck on creating the grid and labeling each spot with numbers. Here is what I have so far, it outputs a 10x10 grid of 0's.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 10;
    const int COLUMNS = 10;
    cout << "Grid\n" << endl;

    int arrayxy [ROWS][COLUMNS] = {{1-10},{10-20},{20-30},{30-40},{40-50},
                                   {50-60},{60-70},{70-80},{80-90},{90-100}};

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; ++j)
    {
        arrayxy[i][j] = 0;
        cout << arrayxy[i][j];
    }
    cout << '\n';
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you write `arrayxy[i][j] = 0;`, why would you expect it to output something different than the `0` you just put into it in the next line of code?

Answer (score 3):

The C++ library provide [std::random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) which can be used to generate random numbers within a range. Given the value for ASCII characters (see [ASCIITable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/)), you would need a range `94` to generate random characters between `' '` (space) and `'~'` (ASCII values `32` to `126`). You can simply generate values in the range of `0-94` and add `' '` to the value.

A simple implementation would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

#define ROWS 10
#define COLS ROWS
#define NCHR 94

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    int arrayxy [ROWS][COLS] = {{0}};
    random_device rd;    /* delcare the randon number generator device */
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, NCHR); /* create disribution */

    /* fill arrayxy with random char */
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            arrayxy[i][j] = dist(rd) + ' ';     /* assign random value */

    /* output arrayxy */
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            cout << "  " << (char)arrayxy[i][j];
        cout << '\n';
    }
    cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rand_10x10
  ,  i  i  0  +  h  >  3  O  ^
  }  j  c  p  y  l  q  >  z  X
  '  F  9  $  O  /  >  /  ,  }
  j  K  W  b  A  r  c  n  Z  m
  q  y  g  1  >  &  9  h  Y  k
  <  @  K  *  '  v  -  O  3  |
  l  l  :  ?  ;  1  c  =  +  <
  k  ;  6  u  p  }  -  e  E  m
  ,  f  %  d  C  \  J  w  :  [
  {  n  x  N  a  $  *  g  l  Y
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: You should use `const` or `constexpr` instead of `#define`, it's better practice. I would also not use `using namespace std`.

Comment: I agree with you on both points. I use `#define` out of habit for constants as it applies to both C and C++. I simply included the `using namespace std` as it was in the original question and this was a single-source file without any possibility of header file multiple inclusion problems. (but worth noting as the generic inclusion of `using namespace std` has drawbacks)